# Prove that for every number $n\geq 5$ there exists a graph with $n$ vertices, all of which have degree $4$.

Tags: graph-theory

Prove that for every number $n\geq 5$ there exists a graph with $n$ vertices, all of which have degree $4$.

I'm not sure how to do this. I've tried a few things. I was thinking induction, the base case is $K_5$ and then I assumed the result was true from some number $k$ and then considered $k+1$ vertices, but I don't know how to proceed.

The other approach I had was to construct the graph it asked for: Consider a cycle with $n$ vertices, all of the vertices have degree $2$. Now connect each vertex by an edge to the neighbor of the vertices they're adjacent to. This process works for all $n$, but I don't know how to show that it terminates.

Any solutions or help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Your direct construction idea works fine. For concreteness, consider the following.

Enumerate all $n$ vertices $v_1, \ldots v_n$ and attach $v_i$ to $v_j$ if
$$i \equiv j \pm 1 \mod n \ \ \ \ {or} \ \ \ \ i \equiv j \pm 2 \mod n.$$
One can then check from here that this satisfies our requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Your second way is more successful. You can also reason like this.
Let us number the vertices of the cycle of length $n$ as the residues modulo $n$ $(0, 1, ..., n-1)$. Choose an integer $m\neq1$ and $m<n$ relatively prime to $n$. Then the set $\{0, m, 2m, ..., (n-1)m\}$ is a complete set of residues modulo $n$. Now connect the vertices of our cycle sequentially as $0 - r_1 - r_2 -\ldots- r_{n-1} - 0$, where $0<r_k<n$ and $r_k\equiv km\pmod n$.